# Protocol function with generic type

Tags: swift, generics, types, swift-protocols, associated-types

I would like to create a protocol like the following:

```swift
protocol Parser {
    func parse() -> ParserOutcome<?>
}

enum ParserOutcome<Result> {
    case result(Result)
    case parser(Parser)
}
```

I want to have parsers that return either a result of a specific type, or another parser.

If I use an associated type on `Parser`, then I can't use `Parser` in the `enum`. If I specify a generic type on the `parse()` function, then I can't define it in the implementation without a generic type.

How can I achieve this?

---

Using generics, I could write something like this:

```swift
class Parser<Result> {
    func parse() -> ParserOutcome<Result> { ... }
}

enum ParserOutcome<Result> {
    case result(Result)
    case parser(Parser<Result>)
}
```

This way, a `Parser` would be parameterized by the result type. `parse()` can return a result of the `Result` type, or any kind of parser that would output either a result of the `Result` type, or another parser parameterized by the same `Result` type.

With associated types however, as far as I can tell, I'll always have a `Self` constraint:

```swift
protocol Parser {
    associatedtype Result

    func parse() -> ParserOutcome<Result, Self>
}

enum ParserOutcome<Result, P: Parser where P.Result == Result> {
    case result(Result)
    case parser(P)
}
```

In this case, I can't have any type of parser that would return the same `Result` type anymore, it has to be the same type of parser.

I would like to obtain the same behavior with the `Parser` protocol as I would with a generic definition, and I would like to be able to do that within the bounds of the type system, without introducing new boxed types, just like I can with a normal generic definition.

It seems to me that defining `associatedtype OutcomeParser: Parser` inside the `Parser` protocol, then returning an `enum` parameterized by that type would solve the problem, but if I try to define `OutcomeParser` that way, I get the error:

> Type may not reference itself as a requirement

Comment: I can't really write up an answer for this myself, but it looks to me like you might be looking for _type erasure_. I know that @RobNapier has shown elegant use of it in some of this answers, maybe you can find something to investigate there.

Comment: I'm looking for language support. If it requires a hack, then I'd rather not implement it.

Comment: I don't believe that type erasure is to be considered a hack, but rather a technique (which I haven't mastered myself :). I think I read somewhere that the Swift stdlib itself makes use of type erasure at some places. (Also, since I haven't really grasped type erasure myself, it might be totally off to use it in this context).

Comment: Hmm, indeed, `AnySequence` is using type erasure, it's in the standard library, and it's explicitly documented as "type erased" by Apple. So far, it still feels like a hack, but I'm looking more into it.

Comment: Type erasures are not a hack. They are used across the Swift Standard Library. You can read more about them here - https://www.natashatherobot.com/swift-type-erasure/.

Comment: Your solution using a generic class seems good to me. What are you trying to gain by using a protocol instead? Avoid explicitly plumbing the `Result` type as a generic type parameter?

Comment: @pyon, I would like to be able to describe this with a protocol, because the implementor might not necessarily be a `class`. I could, and actually do have, a simple `struct` parser, but I could just as well have a large, complex, multi-branched, `class` parser.

Comment: @pyon, also, I would like to use composition, not inheritance. If I were to have a `class`, then I'd be forced to subclass it, which is something I don't want to do, especially since there are no `abstract` classes in Swift.

Comment: @rid: Ah, makes perfect sense. It seems to me that you want to define a subtype of your `Parser` protocol (“subprotocol”?) by forcing its associated `Result` type to coincide with another type defined elsewhere (in this case, `ParserOutcome`'s `Result`). But AFAICT, this isn't possible in Swift. I'd love to be wrong, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Status of the features needed to make this work:

- Recursive protocol constraints ([SE-0157](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0157-recursive-protocol-constraints.md)) **Implemented (Swift 4.1)**
- Arbitrary requirements in protocols ([SE-0142](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0142-associated-types-constraints.md)) **Implemented (Swift 4)**
- Generic Type Aliases ([SE-0048](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0048-generic-typealias.md)) **Implemented (Swift 3)**

---

Looks like this is currently not possible without introducing boxed types (the "type erasure" technique), and is something looked at for a future version of Swift, as described by the [Recursive protocol constraints](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/GenericsManifesto.md#recursive-protocol-constraints-) and [Arbitrary requirements in protocols](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/GenericsManifesto.md#arbitrary-requirements-in-protocols-) sections of the [Complete Generics Manifesto](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/GenericsManifesto.md) (since [generic protocols](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/GenericsManifesto.md#generic-protocols) are not going to be supported).

When Swift supports these two features, the following should become valid:

```swift
protocol Parser {
    associatedtype Result
    associatedtype SubParser: Parser where SubParser.Result == Result

    func parse() -> ParserOutcome<Result, SubParser>
}

enum ParserOutcome<Result, SubParser: Parser where SubParser.Result == Result> {
    case result(Result)
    case parser(P)
}
```

With [generic `typealias`es](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/GenericsManifesto.md#generic-typealiases), the subparser type could also be extracted as:

```swift
typealias SubParser<Result> = Parser where SubParser.Result == Result
```

Comment: I mentioned type erasure above, but maybe you can adapt [recursive enumerations](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html) to help you out along the way (keyword `indirect case`).

Comment: @dfri, true, I edited the question though to mention that I would like to be able to do that within the bounds of the type system, without introducing new boxed types, just like I can with a normal generic definition. I did consider `indirect` enumerations, but I don't think that would work in my case, since the `Parser` itself is not an enumeration, but rather something that needs to contain logic.

Comment: Yeah I tried myself to make use of recursive enums to construct a parser such as the one above, however without success (thought I'd add it in case someone else could make use of the construct more creatively.)

Answer (score 6):

I wouldn't be so quick to dismiss type erasures as "hacky" or "working around [...] the type system" – in fact I'd argue that they work *with* the type system in order to provide a useful layer of abstraction when working with protocols (and as already mentioned, used in the standard library itself e.g [`AnySequence`](http://swiftdoc.org/v3.0/type/AnySequence/), [`AnyIndex`](http://swiftdoc.org/v3.0/type/AnyIndex/) & [`AnyCollection`](http://swiftdoc.org/v3.0/type/AnyCollection/)).

As you said yourself, all you want to do here is have the possibility of either returning a given result from a parser, or another parser that works with the same result type. We don't care about the specific implementation of that parser, we just want to know that it has a `parse()` method that returns a result of the same type, or another parser with that same requirement.

A type erasure is perfect for this kind of situation, as all you need to do is take a reference to a given parser's `parse()` method, allowing you to abstract away the rest of the implementation details of that parser. It's important to note that you aren't losing any type safety here, you're being exactly as precise about the type of the parser as you requirement specifies.

If we look at a potential implementation of a type-erased parser, `AnyParser`, hopefully you'll see what I mean:

```
struct AnyParser<Result> : Parser {

    // A reference to the underlying parser's parse() method
    private let _parse : () -> ParserOutcome<Result>

    // Accept any base that conforms to Parser, and has the same Result type
    // as the type erasure's generic parameter
    init<T:Parser where T.Result == Result>(_ base:T) {
        _parse = base.parse
    }

    // Forward calls to parse() to the underlying parser's method
    func parse() -> ParserOutcome<Result> {
        return _parse()
    }
}
```

Now in your `ParserOutcome`, you can simply specify that the `parser` case has an associated value of type `AnyParser<Result>` – i.e any kind of parsing implementation that can work with the given `Result` generic parameter.

```
protocol Parser {
    associatedtype Result
    func parse() -> ParserOutcome<Result>
}

enum ParserOutcome<Result> {
    case result(Result)
    case parser(AnyParser<Result>)
}

...

struct BarParser : Parser {
    func parse() -> ParserOutcome<String> {
        return .result("bar")
    }
}

struct FooParser : Parser {
    func parse() -> ParserOutcome<Int> {
        let nextParser = BarParser()

        // error: Cannot convert value of type 'AnyParser<Result>'
        // (aka 'AnyParser<String>') to expected argument type 'AnyParser<_>'
        return .parser(AnyParser(nextParser))
    }
}

let f = FooParser()
let outcome = f.parse()

switch outcome {
case .result(let result):
    print(result)
case .parser(let parser):
    let nextOutcome = parser.parse()
}
```

You can see from this example that Swift is still enforcing type-safety. We're trying to wrap a `BarParser` instance (that works with `String`s) in an `AnyParser` type erased wrapper that expects an `Int` generic parameter, resulting in a compiler error. Once `FooParser` is parameterised to work with `String`s instead of `Int`, the compiler error will be resolved.

---

In fact, as `AnyParser` in this case only acts as a wrapper for a single method, another potential solution (if you really detest type erasures) is to simply use this directly as your `ParserOutcome`'s associated value.

```
protocol Parser {
    associatedtype Result
    func parse() -> ParserOutcome<Result>
}

enum ParserOutcome<Result> {
    case result(Result)
    case anotherParse(() -> ParserOutcome<Result>)
}


struct BarParser : Parser {
    func parse() -> ParserOutcome<String> {
        return .result("bar")
    }
}

struct FooParser : Parser {
    func parse() -> ParserOutcome<String> {
        let nextParser = BarParser()
        return .anotherParse(nextParser.parse)
    }
}

...

let f = FooParser()
let outcome = f.parse()

switch outcome {
case .result(let result):
    print(result)
case .anotherParse(let nextParse):
    let nextOutcome = nextParse()
}
```

Comment: Nice! In your second solution, how come we don't need to mark the `parser` case by `indirect`? Is it not an recursive enumeration when the associated value of a case is a closure with _return_ type being the same as the enum?

Comment: @dfri Ah interesting, I didn't even think about that. I suspect it's due to the fact that functions are reference types – therefore no extra level of indirection is needed in order to store a `() -> ParserOutcome<Result>` function in the enum, as a block of memory to store the reference is of known size, and not dependant on the enum itself.

Comment: Ah yes, naturally, that must be it!

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation. I do understand the idea behind the Swift version of type erasure, and I do understand the fact that you don't lose type safety, but what I mean by saying it's a hack, is that you shouldn't *need* to do all these things in order to express your requirements. The Swift team themselves recognize this and say so when speaking about recursive protocol constraints in regards to the `AnySequence` type. Just like me, they don't like the fact that `AnySequence` is the way it is, and they plan on fixing it with the introduction of recursive protocol constraints.

Comment: Also, while I do recognize the fact that the solution is elegant, the fact remains that it is a workaround. It does use the type system to implement the workaround, but it's still a workaround. I shouldn't need to create a new, intermediary concrete type just to express a type constraint, especially one that can be expressed very well using a different feature of the type system (generics).

Comment: @rid Swift is still relatively young! Maybe in Swift 4.0 ... :)

Comment: @dfri, indeed, it's a feature still left to implement. I wouldn't be surprised if Swift 4 does actually implement it, since it seems to be high on the list of priorities (it's actually the first section in the [Complete Generics Manifesto](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/GenericsManifesto.md)).

Comment: @rid I definitely agree that a built in language feature allowing you to express this kind of requirement would be neat – although you should note that there's a subtle difference between using a type erasure here and a recursive protocol associatedtype constraint that would limit a `SubParser` to conform to `Parser`. With an associatedtype, an implementation of `Parser` would be responsible for specifying a specific concrete type of the `SubParser`, rather than accepting 'any parser that deals with the same result'.

Comment: So for that reason I don't think that type erasures will be made redundant any time soon – although Swift is still rapidly evolving and it'll definitely be interesting to see where they go with this.

Comment: @originaluser2, hmm, you mean that `associatedtype` or `typealias` can only refer to concrete types?

Comment: @rid Currently when constrained to a protocol, an associatedtype must be satisfied by a concrete type, although this is potentially a bug and may be changed in a future version of Swift (see this [bug report](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1581)). Depending on how this is resolved, it could indeed open up more expressive ways of doing a type erasure, which would indeed be neat. Although this still may not completely make type erasures redundant as they can be used in other places than protocol requirements (e.g when defining an array of a protocol type that has a given associatedtype).

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want to use a generic constraint on the `ParserOutcome` enum.

```
enum ParserOutcome<Result, P: Parser where P.Result == Result> {
    case result(Result)
    case parser(P)
}
```

This way you would not be able to use `ParserOutcome` with anything that is not conforming to the `Parser` protocol. You can actually add one more constraint to make it better. Adding the constraint that the result of the `Parser` outcome will be the same type as the `Parser`'s associated type.

Comment: That's true, thanks, but the issue of the return type of `parse()` still remains: how can I define it such that it can take any kind of `Parser`, not just `Self`?

Comment: Oh, I get it now. Current versions of Swift don't allow recursive protocol constraints. I think it was discussed into the Swift evolution mailing list, but will not be included into the Swift 3.0 release. I think that for now type erasures might be your best bet.

Comment: Indeed, looking now at type erasure, it does seem pretty elegant, but it's definitely a hack (even if it's official), because it's working around a limitation in the type system. It would be great if protocols could be generic, but until that happens (or until recursive references are implemented), boxing a type in a type-erased container seems to be a necessary workaround.